# prompt (PS1) doesn't update on bound command

Tags: bash, prompt, readline

I don't understand why these two different ways to use the same command lead to different behaviors.

I've installed [`fzf`](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf) and [`fd`](https://github.com/sharkdp/fd) and have the following lines in `.bashrc`

```
function updir(){
  cd ..
}
function overdir(){
  cd `fd -t d -d 1 | fzf`
}
function downdir(){
  cd `fd -t d -d 8 | fzf`
}

bind -x '"\C-i":"updir"'
bind -x '"\C-j":"overdir"'
bind -x '"\C-l":"downdir"'

export PS1="[\u@\h:\W]$ "
```

If I type `overdir` in the shell I can type a pattern and go to a directory as expected, and the current working directory updates in the prompt, like so

```
[davidlittle@deus1:~]$ overdir
[davidlittle@deus1:googledrive]$ overdir
[davidlittle@deus1:Preferences]$
```

Note that inbetween these prompts an `fzf` window is revealed, I select a directory, and then the view returns to what is shown above. *However*, if I do the same thing using the bound shortcut "C-j" instead of , now I get something different:

```
[davidlittle@deus1:Preferences]$
[davidlittle@deus1:Preferences]$ ls
%Users%davidlittle%googledrive%Preferences%vscode%settings.json keybindings.json                                                settings.json
[davidlittle@deus1:vscode]$
```

As you can see the directory listed in the prompt is `Preferences` on line 2. But this was after hitting `C-j` and selecting the `vscode` directory. Once I call `ls` the correct directory is shown in the prompt.

The expected behavior is that line 2 of the second example should display `vscode` not `Preferences`.

What's going wrong???

Comment: what happens if you hit `enter` key by itself, instead of the `ls` command?

Comment: what happens if you add `ls` as the second command into `overdir()`?

Comment: what is the result of `C-i`?  ..... how about the result of multiple presses of `C-i`?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @jsotola's questions, and some experimentation, I managed to solve this problem myself.

First, the `-x` isn't necessary, and seemed to be causing problems (when I hit enter, as @jsotola asked, that changes $PS1, so I could probably also include the key combination for enter inside the binding, but I'm not sure how to do that and I think I prefer seeing what the last command was); second, the control commands were working poorly (since they map to other key combinations depending on the terminal) so I switched to using the meta key. Here are the final, working bindings:

```
function updir(){
  cd ..
  exa --long --group-directories-first
}
function indir(){
  cd "`fd -t d -d 1 | fzf`"
  exa --long --group-directories-first
}
function deepdir(){
  cd "`fd -t d -d 8 | fzf`"
  exa --long --group-directories-first
}


bind '"\ek":"updir\n"'
bind '"\ej":"indir\n"'
bind '"\el":"deepdir\n"'
```

Note that these new bindings also include a command to display the directory using [`exa`](https://the.exa.website/). Turns bash into a pretty clean file explorer with fuzzy matching!!